# Nonnull annotations and standard java packages

Tags: java, annotations, findbugs

I'm trying to add findbugs-compatible annotations to a project, but noticed that @Nonnull is not always processed as I'd expect. For example findbugs does not assume that standard native collections can return null:

```
void method(@Nonnull String bar) {...}

map = new HashMap();
method(map.get("foo"));
```

will pass the findbugs tests even though it shouldn't. Can I configure findbugs somehow to make it alert in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

according to documentation,

The annotated element must not be null. Annotated Fields must only not be null after construction has completed. Annotated methods must have non-null return values.

```
@Documented
@Target(value={FIELD,METHOD,PARAMETER,LOCAL_VARIABLE})
@Retention(value=CLASS)
@Nonnull(when=ALWAYS)
@TypeQualifierNickname
public @interface NonNull
```

or you can use @DefaultAnnotation(NonNull.class) on a class or package, and then use @Nullable only on those parameters, methods or fields that you want to allow to be null.

the analysis is done on source.

so try this, it works for me

```
/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    method( getValue());
}

private static void method(@NonNull Object obj){
    System.out.println(obj);
}

@CheckForNull
private static Object getValue(){
    Map map = new HashMap();
    return map.get("foo");
}
```

or you can try a Design By Contract using http://c4j.sourceforge.net/

Comment: This doesn't appear to answer the question at all.  The question was whether it's possible to get Findbugs to realise that HashMap can return null, not how to use the Nonnull annotation in general.

Comment: ok, instead of hashmap, create a class say new XTZClass(), xyzObj.get(""), inside the method return null in a conditional block. if that is identified by the findbug, it is aware of object graph and class at runtime. this is just a suggestion

Comment: i am not sure about whether static analysis will work on already compiled libraries

Comment: @hGx Yes, that works, but it's not a feasible solution for me. I want to deal with an existing project. It would be too many files / packages / things to change. I'm looking for something seemless / more automatic.

Comment: want to try something similar to c4j ?